# finding solutions by factoring

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, factoring

How would you find the integer solutions to $a^2-b^2=16$?

I know that the factors of $16$ are $8*2,$ $4*4,$ and $16*1.$ How would I use this?

I know that $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)=16,$ but how would you find to the solutions to it? I know that you can plug in numbers to find the answers, but is there another way of doing this?

Comment: The graph of this function is a hyperbola. There is no point solution but a graph of points that satisfy the equation .

Comment: I am under the impression that you might want integer solutions?

Comment: are you looking for integer solutions like $a=5$ and $b=3$?

Comment: @Tunococ Yes I am

Comment: @ir7 Yes I am lokking for integer solutions

Comment: @calton Then you should try factoring $16$ too. List all possible ways to factor $16$ into a product of two integers, then try to find $a$ and $b$ to match them.

Comment: Recognize that $a^2 = b^2 + 4^2$. The only Pythagorean triple that includes $4$ is $(3,4,5)$. Also $b=0$, $a=4$.

Comment: @Tunococ If we factor $16$ it would be $2*2*2*2.$ It has $16$ divisors. So $16=8*2 and 4*4 and 16*1$

Comment: @calton That is right. So in each of the three cases you listed, can you find $a$ and $b$ to match the two numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We wish to find integer solutions for $a$ and $b$ such that $a^2-b^2=16$.

Factoring the expression we obtain $(a+b)(a-b)=16$.

This means that $(a+b)|16$ and $(a-b)|16$.

From this we can find a set $(a+b)\in \{-16,-8,-4,-2,-1,1,2,4,8,16\}$.

So we obtain the equations

$a+b=-16 \implies a-b=-1$

$a+b=-8 \implies a-b=-2$

$a+b=-4 \implies a-b =-4$

$a+b =-2 \implies a-b =-8$

$a+b = -1 \implies a-b=-16$

$a+b= 1 \implies a-b=16$

$a+b=2 \implies a-b = 8$

$a+b=4 \implies a-b = 4$

$a+b=8 \implies a-b = 2$

$a+b=16 \implies a-b=1$

Now for each of these there is a corresponding matrix (e.g. the first set of equations has been done below:
\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 1 &-16\\
1 & -1 &-1\\
\end{array}\right)\end{align*}
Which we may factor into row echelon form
\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{cc|c}
1 & 1 &-16\\
0 & -2 & 15\\
\end{array}\right)\end{align*}

To get the solution of $b=-7.5$ and $a=-8.5$.

This is not an integer solution so we may discard it. Now continue this process for the remaining 9 pairs of equations.

Comment: how can we find the integer solutions though

Comment: @calton I missed this, let me edit it.

Comment: Sure you can edit it.

Comment: @calton Hopefully this fixes my past error.

Comment: That is a nice way of doing it. I did not figure out the last part of it until I saw this. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a temporary pair of new variables:  Call $u=a+b$ and $v=a-b$.  Notice that if $a$ and $b$ are integers, then $u$ and $v$ will be too.  Notice also that if you know values for $u$ and $v$ it is a straightforward matter to figure out what $a$ and $b$ are.

Now the equation to solve is $uv=16$.  So just list all of the pairs of integers that multiply to be $16$:  $1 \cdot 16$, $2 \cdot 8$, etc.  Those give you the integer values of $u$ and $v$; use those to find the values of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Maybe one should add that $u$ and $v$ should be chosen to be both even, and possibly negative.

Comment: I thought about adding the stipulation that $u$ and $v$ need to be both even, but worst case scenario is you find values of $a$ and $b$ that are half-integers, and than you discard them.